# HTML Elements by Yandex qa tools with Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to integrate and use yandex html elements in my framework.
What i did:

1. Added dependency

   ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements
        htmlelements-java
        1.8
2. In my Base page i'm initializing pages through PageFactory like this:

   public abstract class Base {

   ```
    @Autowired
    public WebDriver driver;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        HtmlElementLoader.populatePageObject(this, driver);
    }

    public abstract boolean isOpened();
   ```

   }
3. Extend Base and expect everything to work:

@Page
public class HeaderPage extends Base {

```
@Autowired
private SearchResultsComponent searchResultsComponent;
@Autowired
private MainMenuComponent mainMenuComponent;

@FindBy(css = ".search")
private WebElement edtSearchField;

@FindBy(css = ".menu")
private WebElement lnkMainMenu;

public MainMenuComponent mainMenu() {
    return mainMenuComponent;
}

@Step
public SearchResultsComponent searchResults() {
    return searchResultsComponent;
}

@Step
public void search(String searchValue) {
    edtSearchField.sendKeys(searchValue);
    Waiter.waitABit(3000);
}

@Step
public void openMainMenu() {
    lnkMainMenu.click();
}

@Override
public boolean isOpened() {
    return wait.until((d) -> this.edtSearchField.isDisplayed());
}
```

}

It throws an exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'headerPage': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'searchResultsComponent'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchResultsComponent': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Once try Adding these dependency to your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately